# How to print "v-card"s and "v-app-bar"s simultaneously

Tags: vuetify.js

Suppose you have many "v-card" with different heights using Vuetify.

The v-app-bar and v-cards are displayed as expected on screen, but the v-cards at the top of all pages are overlaid by the v-app-bar on print.

For example, we have many 15 "v-card"s on one page on screen, compared to we have two pages on print.
On the first print page, we can see v-app-bar and v-cards number 1 to 7. On the last print page, we can see v-card number 8 overlaid partially　by v-app-bar and other v-cards number 9 to 15.

Like as follows

Print pages I want
[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nKn8.png)

Print pages I got
[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7uJ1.png)

Please forgive the difference in the number of v-cards in the example.
What is important is whether v-card No.8 is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your v-app-bar be fixed to the top of the screen.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#scroll-behavior

If you want to make full screenshot of your page.

https://zapier.com/blog/full-page-screenshots-in-chrome/